# What is the intuition behind the method of characteristics for a second order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition, characteristics

I understand the idea behind the method of characteristics as applied to first-order PDEs: watching how $u(x,y)$ changes along special curves $(x(s),y(s))$ simplifies the problem to a set of coupled ODEs.

What does the method of characteristics mean for second-order (hyperbolic) PDEs? All I see is that we perform a smart change of coordinates $(x,y) \to (\xi,\eta)$ to obtain a simpler PDE. What is the intuition behind this change of variables?

Comment: The question isn't clear and there seems to be some confusion. There is no method of characteristics for second order PDEs, only first order PDEs. You can write a second order PDE as a system of first order PDEs and then apply the method of characteristics. A change of variables is entirely different from applying the method of characteristics; usually you search for coordinates $(\xi, \eta)$ that put your second order PDE into a [canonical form](https://primer-computational-mathematics.github.io/book/c_mathematics/differential_equations/8_pde_second_order.html).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I think I understand what you mean. The process of converting a second order PDE to a canonical form only has a step that involves solving some resulting first-order PDEs using the method of characteristics. Is that right?